# Plane/Face from Coordinates using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a solid mesh from a set of planar coordinates. I've tried a bunch of things, but only 2 methods have got me close to the desired result.

Method 1: I tried to add in a quadrilateral curve using 4 points, then converted that to a mesh, but the mesh is edges only, no face - I'd like to continue this method, so if there's a way to fill the mesh that would be great. The FillCurve node only works with Z=0.

Method 2: Create a Grid with 2x2 vertices, then modify the location of each vertex - this worked, but is way too convoluted - an easier method must exist.

The image below shows the two methods.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: nope, there is no easier way, except you use animation nodes or something else. But of course you could use the curve thing, if you first create your coordinates in that way, that z=0, then use fill curve and change the "missing" values afterwards or rotate/move/scale it, that your coordinates fit.

Comment: `Curve to Mesh` with `Curve Line` and `Quadrilateral` as profile ...?

Comment: I Tried this option - the problem is that the coordinates are not orthogonal, so I need to calculate the normal vector for the direction of the `Curve Line`, and to do that, I need a face, so we're back to the original problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you could not achieve a solution with `Curve to Mesh` in your case, the following setup might help you:

[image]

Here I create a curve with `Quadrilateral`, which allows the comfortable definition of the four corner points.

But I use this only as a container from which I transfer the positions to the corner points of a grid.

In the next step I extrude this grid, flip the original face and merge the two resulting objects with `Merge by Distance`.

If I understood the question correctly, this should be exactly what you are looking for.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks - that's basically the same as my second attempt, but much neater. The Transfer Attribute and Set Position Nodes make it a lot less complicated!